# echo gammu environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to write a script that uses some environtment variables that are set by the sms sending/receiving program gammu. These variables are set at the moment when messages are received/sent and are not accessible otherwise. This means that the script must run by the daemon to make use of these variables. This isn't a problem, but actually accessing these! 
This is the example script I am trying to run from withing gammu.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq $SMS_MESSAGES` ; do
        echo SMS_"${i}"_NUMBER SMS_"${i}"_TEXT >> smslog.dat
done
```

Basically I want to make a log of all the messages received. However with the above script all I get is SMS_1_NUMBER SMS_1_TEXT. How can I get the values stored in these variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script could do just

```
env | grep -E '^SMS_.*_(NUMBER|TEXT)=' >>smslog.dat
```

Alternatively,

```
i=1

while [ "$i" -le "$SMS_MESSAGES" ]; do
    printf 'Message %d number = "%s"\n' "$i" "$( eval printf '%s' "\$SMS_${i}_NUMBER" )"
    printf 'Message %d text   = "%s"\n' "$i" "$( eval printf '%s' "\$SMS_${i}_TEXT" )"

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done >>smslog.dat
```

To be sure that you write to `smslog.dat` in the correct location, either use `cd` in your script to the correct directory, or specify `smslog.dat` with its full path.

Comment: thank you for your answer but for some reason nothing is written in the smslog.dat with the second option which I would prefer.

Comment: @lucian If you add `echo "$SMS_MESSAGES"` at the top before the loop, what does it print?

Comment: when i send a message I get in the gammu log file the correct output: Subprocess output: 1. This means that gammu has launched the script and processed it

Comment: @lucian I have just now fixed two syntax errors (missing `"` in two places). Sorry about that, try again.

Comment: still no joy! nothing is written. i have created the empty file prior to lanching the script and still nothing

Comment: @lucian The script assumes that the variables are exported and available to the script. It also assumes that `smslog.dat` is located in the current directory from where the script is executing. It may be that the script is not executing from where you think it is. You may see the current working directory path by `echo "$PWD"` in the script.

Comment: I tried again with the smslog.dat in the same folder as the script and still nothing. I have echoed the other variables too and I get the correct answers so they are present and can be read but not in a loop. So if I echo $SMS_1_NUMBER and echo $SMS_1_TEXT it works. But not if instead of 1 I put ${i} from the for (or while) loop. Much too weird for me!

Comment: @lucian Sure, that tells you that it's executing `/home/pi/scripts/test.sh` which I presume is your script, but it doesn't say what the directory that acts as the current working directory is (it is not automatically `/home/pi/scripts` unless you `cd` there inside the script).  You may obviously also give the absolute pathname to the `smslog.dat` file in the script as you are writing to it, e.g. `done >>/home/pi/scripts/smslog.dat`.

Comment: could it be easier to do this in python? (much less experience with that one but I am willing to learn!)

Comment: @lucian Not my cup of tea, and too big a machine for what should be a trivial task.

Comment: you were right! full path to the smslog.dat file was the answer! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @lucian Good! That means that you now also have _another_ `smslog.dat` somewhere on the system (probably, from the previous runs).

Comment: that is not a problem, since this is a test system anyway. I am using it to prototype this script and add some functionality to it. thank you for your help!